# MailApp.sendEmail -> mail coming from different accounts

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using a script in a shared spreadsheet to send update emails to the working team. 
I am using a simple call:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(mail_address, subject, msg);
```

It worked fine for some time.. But now I have a strange behavior: the script runs successfully but the emails are actually sent randomly by one of the users which the spreadhsheet is shared with.. 
I can't understand how that is possible since they are not shared accounts and it shouldn't be possible to send emails like that..

**Edit**: The script is executed by a trigger based on the editing of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Perhaps you should report it as an issue to Google.

Comment: How is the script executing? Manually, from the editor? Is it always the same account which executes it?

Comment: The script is executed by a trigger based on the editing of the spreadsheet. Basically the spreadsheet is a checklist for  different users. When an user flags a cell, the function sends a mail notification by email..

Comment: Since you're sending emails, I'm assuming you have **installed** the trigger? If that's the case, then the script will not execute as the account editing the spreadsheet, but as the account that installed the trigger.

Comment: What if many have installed the trigger?

Comment: I posted an answer. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Situation:

- You have installed an `onEdit` trigger for all users which have edit access to the spreadsheet.
- The function trigged by this trigger sends an email.
- You are noticing that the emails are not always being sent by the user that edited the spreadsheet.

#### Issue:

The problem is that, as you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions):

> **Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them**.

This means **the email will not be sent by the user that edited the spreadsheet, but by the one who installed the trigger**. Since several users installed this trigger, your project might contain several duplicate triggers, each of which will run on behalf of a different account. Because of this, you might end up receiving multiple emails for one single spreadsheet edition, each of them sent by a different account.

#### Solution:

If you want to send a single email every time the spreadsheet is edited, and send this email from the account that edited the spreadsheet, you can use the methods `getActiveUser()` and `getEffectiveUser()`:

- [Session.getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()) refers to the current user, that is to say, the user that just edited the spreadsheet.
- [Session.getEffectiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser) refers to the user under whose authority the script is running. That is to say, the user who installed the trigger.

The idea is to check whether the `active user` and the `effective user` are the same one, and send an email only if that's the case. This way, even if multiple functions are trigged by a single edition (one for each account that installed the trigger), only one email will be sent (the one corresponding to the user who edited the spreadsheet).

#### Code sample:

```js
function onEditTrigger(e) {
  var activeUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var effectiveUser = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  if (activeUser === effectiveUser) {
    // Rest of code
    MailApp.sendEmail(mail_address, subject, msg);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- If you have installed the trigger, you better not name your function `onEdit`: this name is reserved for a simple trigger.

#### Reference:

- [Installable triggers: Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions)