# send email from currently logged in user when checkbox is TRUE

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

My question is an extension of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68007244/google-sheets-send-email-when-checkbox-is-changed-to-true) fantastic solution but am hoping to take it one step further.  Whenever a user other than me marks the checkbox as TRUE, the sender of the email is always me, since:

> Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them

**Is it possible to capture the user currently logged in and make them the sender, and if so, what am I missing in my code to make that happen?**

## What I've tried

I believed I had found my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61596597/mailapp-sendemail-mail-coming-from-different-accounts), but no such luck.  This still posts the timestamp to the sheet successfully, but the email sender still shows as me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Edit(s):

I noticed in the above solution `if (activeUser === effectiveUser) {` only "worked" if typed as `if (activeUser !== effectiveUser) {`.  In my attempts at making it work, I made that edit and forgot to revert it.

```
function sendEmail(e){
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = e.range;
  var activeUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var effectiveUser = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  
  if (activeUser !== effectiveUser) {

    Logger.log(cell.getColumn());
    Logger.log(cell.isChecked());
    //Check if the checkbox in column G(index 7) was checked
    if(sheet.getName() == "actionItems" && cell.getColumn() == 7 && cell.isChecked()){

      //get current row values from column A to column F
      var values = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),1,1,6).getDisplayValues().flat();
      Logger.log(values);
      var transmittalNumber = values[0];
      var email = values[5];
      var query = values[1];

      //create and update the email's hmtl body
      var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('html_template');
      templ.query = query;
      var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();

      //Send email
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: email,
        subject: "Oatsies Action Item: "+transmittalNumber,
        htmlBody: message
      });

      //Add timestamp at column H(index 8)
      var timeZone = "GMT-7";
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),timeZone, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
      sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),8).setValue(date);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your function declaration?

Comment: @Cooper I'm fairly new a coding and this was compiled from a few different answers.  I'm planning to pick up a Javascript book from the library to dig into this a little more.  It seems like you're referring to confusion on my end between a declaration and an expression?

Comment: @Nate the problem was that some part of the code whas put in the same place line as the code fences. I fixed that in my edit from Jan 21.

Comment: @Rubén thanks for correcting that.  I do have that in my code, but must have a mistakenly omitted it when I copied and pasted it here.  Because of that, unfortunately, my problem still exists.

Comment: Frustratingly, I've still made no forward progress on this, just spinning my wheels.  I was hoping @Ron M might happen to see the question since he wrote 99% of the code in the post lined above.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> Is it possible to capture the user currently logged in and make them the sender?

If you are using a free Google account (usually gmail.com account) it might be possible if you use the Gmail API and set a way for active users to authorize the access to their Gmail account to send emails. Also it might be possible if you and the user are using a Google Workspace accounts and if you are able to take advantage of company-wide delegation of authority (also might be possible if you are able to configure the user's email addresses as emails aliases of your account).

Regarding the use of `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` it will return the active user email based on a complex rules i.e. your account and active user belongs to the same Google Workspace domains.

Related

- [Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() results are inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33664758/1595451)
- [Domain-wide delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55329895/1595451)
- [getActiveUser() doesn't return the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57847178/1595451)

Comment: I appreciate the input, but to be clear, I was looking for specific coding help versus the more general answer of whether or not it was conceptually possible.  I see now that my question was worded as the latter so I've updated it in the original post.

Comment: @Nate question updates should not invalidate an appropriate answer, if that will happens you should post a new question.

Comment: I don't feel the edit I made constitutes a categorical change.  On the contrary I feel that you misunderstood what was originally being asked, and updated it to make that more clear.  I didn't go through the trouble of posting code with a full description of what I have tried previously along with the the result (problem)  I was encountering all to pose the preemptive question of "theoretically would this be possible."  I am seeing assistance on determining what I have incorrect in my code.